# Linux not registering external DVI monitor

Tags: monitor, dvi

We have a Linux computer (Ubuntu 20.04) but currently it is not registering an external monitor with DVI cable. When we go to the Display Setting the screen does not show up.

Thank you.

Comment: A lot more details is needed. Is it a laptop? Then probably you need to switch it on using Fn key.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and post hardware specifications.